# Reference textbox from chart expression in QlikView

Tags: qlikview

Please advise (syntax) on how to reference a text object in QlikView to pick its value.

My object is called: TX1, it is a text box and it is defined like this: 
`=SUM( TOTAL Income)`

Why do I need this?

I have a chart with Persons as a dimension, and the expression should calculate `each person's income/total income`.

The `total income` needs to be taken from that textbox with alternate state so it remains unaffected by the filter selections (or the dimension that forces total income to be seen as total income belonging to each person).

Thank you.

Comment: I tried this, but variables don't have alternate state unfortunately so it wouldn't work. It would be great to just know how to reference TX1 from the chart expression. I tried Object.TX1, Objects(TX1)... no luck so far. The syntax is what troubles me. Thanks a lot oGeez!

Comment: oGeez, not if you set a different alternate state to it and make no selections in that alternate state. You can add an alternate state to document settings and then set an object to use that state from object properties - general.

Comment: I understand now. Could you set the value initially on opening the document and then refer to it later? (See answer)

Comment: I would use the alternate state within Set Analysis expression: sum(income)/sum({[AltStateGroup]} total income)

Answer (score 1):

Any selections you make in your dashboard will have an effect on relational data shown within a text-box.

You can, however, store the initial value of your expression and keep it for later use.

Create a variable called `vInitialSum` or something, and set it upon opening the document. You'll then have the untouched (unfiltered) value of `=SUM("Total Income")` to use at your disposal.

Add the trigger in Settings > Document Properties > Triggers > OnOpen:

[image]

Comment: Thank you oGeez, but I was looking for a fixed value and in the solution you suggest the variable later changes value based on changing filters. I need the value to be preserved no matter what. What could work here is also setting the variable in the script but I don't know the syntax in that case, either. It should be something like Set `v1 = SELECT SUM([Income]) from Table1`; but when I do this, the variable value is set to `SELECT SUM([Income]) from Table1` instead of the actual result of that select statement.

Comment: Hi Samy, setting the variable in this fashion will give the variable the actual value at runtime, not the expression. Any selections you make during your session will not have any effect on the value that has been assigned, as long as you assign it in the `OnOpen` trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
 SUM({1}Income)
```

The "{1}" tells the formula to ignore any selections and calculate on the full data set.  For more details, see "set analysis" and "set modifiers" in the help.